# Trying to open and close workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to open and close feeder files after copying the data from them and pasting in the file in the consolidated file. I wish to have the VBA code and module in the consolidated file that will remain open after running the code. Hope this is clear, if not I can try to be more specific.

There is also a password on the file as well, password for this example is Marrin18, I haven't been able to get it open so I have not coded what it would take to open with a password.

```
Sub consolDirectors()

ExcelApplication.Open.Workbooks ("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx")
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AH227").Copy
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Total 802").Worksheets("Marrin").Range("A1:AH227").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1").Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your sentences don't make any sense. Don't make things complicated for us, try to simplify them. Just focus on your question and ask.

Comment: I tried to update the language to make it more clear does this help?

Comment: And do you want to open and close feeder files after closing the workbook where your data is located? Is this your question?

Comment: I would like to open and close feeder files after copying the data from them and pasting in the file in the consolidated file. I wish to have the VBA code and module in the consolidated file that will remain open after running the code. Hope this is clear, if not I can try to be more specific.

Comment: Yes this is clear thanks, please update your question with your comment.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @TimWilliams I get Run time error'424' Object reequired

Comment: *On which line*?  Please be as specific as you can.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open a workbook to read the contents. However you need to write the contents cell by cell, so this is the downside. If you are ok with a 5 secs macro here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fd()
    Dim FilePath$
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const FileName$ = "2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx"
    Const SheetName$ = "Summary"
    FilePath = "C:\mypath\" ' path to feeder file 2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx

    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then
        MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For i = 1 To 227
        For j = 1 To 34
            Cells(i, j) = GetData(FilePath, FileName, SheetName, Cells(i, j))
        Next j
    Next i
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
End Sub

Private Function GetData(Path, File, Sheet, Rng)
    Dim Data$
    Data = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & Rng.Address(, , xlR1C1)
    GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data)
End Function
```

Comment: I am getting an error message Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope

Comment: @JS Bach Maybe you have a sub called "Feed"? I changed my sub's name to "Fd". Also check if you have GetData elsewhere. If so, change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub consolDirectors()
    Const FPATH As String = "T:\Planning\FY Budget\2018 Budget\" & _ 
                            "Director Templates\With updates\"
    Const RNG_COPY As String = "A1:AH227"
    Dim wb As Workbook

    'you should use the full path here....
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open( _
           FileName:= FPATH & "2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx", _
           Password:= "passHere" )

    'add the file extension here - I'm guessing "xlsx" ?
    Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Total 802.xlsx" _
        ).Worksheets("Marrin").Range(RNG_COPY).Value = 
        wb.Worksheets("Summary").Range(RNG_COPY).Value

    'If this file is the one with the macro you can use ThisWorkbook instead
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Marrin").Range(RNG_COPY).Value = _
    '         wb.Worksheets("Summary").Range(RNG_COPY).Value

    wb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: My file is on a shared drive, the file path is T:\Planning\FY Budget\2018 Budget\Director Templates\With updates. I have code this    Sub consolDirectors()

Dim wb

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(T:\Planning\FY Budget\2018 Budget\Director Templates\With updates but I get the run time error syntax, could you be more specific on what you are suggesting I code, I do not understand your 'comment related to the code, I am very new

Comment: "get the run time error syntax" - what is the error *message*?

Answer (score 0):

@tim williams @Tehscript Here is the code I wound up using, not very advance, but appreicate both your

```
Sub FeedFiles()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= "T:\Planning\FY Budget\2018 Budget\Director Templates\With updates\2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx", Password:="Marrin18"
    Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Activate
    Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AH227").Copy
    Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - Total 802.xlsm").Worksheets("Marrin").Range("A1:AH227").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("2018 Budget PL_HC_CAP - MarrinV1.xlsx").Close 
End Sub
```